# Parsing URLs vs Storing URL Parts

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm using PHP and MySQL, and I'm building a database that needs to store urls. I'm going to have to do a lot of work with the *parts* of the url. It's going to end up being millions of records.

My question is, what makes more sense:

- to store the parts of the url in several fields, negating the need to
  parse
- store the whole url in one field, and parse it out every time

Thanks for any advice you can offer!

Comment: Sorry for my english. What type of data do you need store in each url variable? string? integers?

Comment: If you plan on doing a lot of searching on the specific parts of the URL I would suggest to store them separately.  Depends on what youre searching for and the "work" you'll be doing with the URL.  You could always store the full URL in the db as well in case you need to grab just that instead of putting it all back together.

Comment: It would pretty much be the information returned by [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Will you be querying against the different parts?

Comment: Tim, there's your answer then. I'd split it out. You're trading space for simplicity and the ability to index each part separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb when you design new database schema - is not to denormalize until it is proven that it is necessary.

So start with the most normalized and the simplest schema. And only after you experience any performance issues - **profile** your application and solve the *particular* bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your querying pattern. If you're going to do things like `SELECT * FROM urls WHERE hostname = ....`, then you obviously want them split into their own fields. If you're never going to slice and dice your data using queries, then storing just the full URL itself would be fine. But you ***never*** want to parse db-side (always better to just store your parsed data if you find yourself parsing db-side).

Answer (score 0):

Database structure is really depends on queries you are planning to run.

If you do need search by URL parts like domain name you do need to keep them somewhere else, outside of big urls table(s) to perform these queries against smaller table.